# How to optimize this query? Slow query

Tags: mysql, database, database-optimization

Hi I am Trying to Optimize this Query.
If there are a lot of transactions in the timeframe it can take up to 10 Seconds to execute on my local environment.
I tried to create a Index on the created_at column but it doesn't solve the issue if there are a lot of rows in the table (my table has only 4m rows).
Can someone recommend some optimization tips?

```
select 
   count(*) as total,
   trader_id 
from 
  (select * 
   from `transactions`
   where `created_at` >= '2018-05-04 10:54:00'
   order by `id` desc)
  as `transactions`
 where
   `transactions`.`market_item_id` = 1
    and `transactions`.`market_item_id` is not null
    and `gift` = 0
 group by `trader_id`;
```

Edit:

```
id  select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra

1   SIMPLE  transactions    NULL    range   transactions_market_item_id_foreign,transactions_trader_id_foreign,transactions_created_at_index    transactions_created_at_index   5   NULL    107666  2.41    Using index condition; Using where; Using MRR; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

Comment: Can you share the execution plan?

Comment: i'd move the where clauses that are in the outer query to the inner one. You will have less results selected from the very beginning

Comment: I am note sure why that cannot be one siple query rather than a sub query in a query

Comment: it's a mess - you can combine the inner and outer queries into a single query. You don't need the order by clause. Your "market_item_id is not null" clause makes no sense, because you're also selecting only rows where that column = 1.
Once you do that, an index on created_at, market_item_id, gift should do the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete the (unnecessary) inner query:

```
select 
  count(*) as total,
  trader_id 
from transactions
where created_at >= '2018-05-04 10:54:00'
and market_item_id = 1
and gift = 0
group by trader_id
```

Notes:

- removed inner query, which was unnecessary, added cost, massively increased temp storage requirements and usage and prevented other conditions from being used by any indexes
- removed `order by`, which would have cost a lot but made zero difference to the result
- removed `market_item_id is not null` condition, because `market_item_id = 1` already asserts that
- removed backticks, because I don’t like them

Comment: This works great, but it doesn't improve the perfomance by much. I am trying to get the unique traders in a interval. Do you know a better method? I tried it with Distinct but that improve the performance by much.

Answer (score -1):

The better version of Bohemian query is here -

```
SELECT count(*) as total
      ,trader_id
FROM `transactions`
WHERE `created_at` >= '2018-05-04 10:54:00'
AND `market_item_id` = 1
AND `gift` = 0
GROUP BY `trader_id`
```

Comment: How is it better? It’s exactly the *same* (apart from use of archaic capitalised keywords)

Comment: Apart from the fact, that I like the keywords to be uppercase too, your comma placement is horrible! And as @Bohemian said, the query is the same, there is nothing _better_.

Comment: I think I have seen your earlier answer where you have used another AND Cond as market_item_id is not null.

Comment: @eisbehr, The comma placement is not horrible rather better to use comma like this. If you want to make any column comment in the select clause you can simply comment the whole line. You dont need to explicitely take care of a comma.

Comment: Only for lazy people. Still awful.

Comment: I agree with @eisbehr - the "leading comma" style is not ony unnatural to read but it's actually useless: Its only use is to more easily find missed commas between selected columns, but such a missed comma (which experienced SQL coders rarely do) will cause a syntax exception, and once you've fixed that, the leading comma style ceases to have any use, yet everyone who reads/maintains the query has to cope with the poor readability. Further, every psychological study every done confirms that mixed case is more easily read than all caps.